# What are the differences between using return statement?

Tags: javascript

Using return 1:

```
function factorial(n){
  if(n===0){
    return 1; //or return true;
  }
  return n * factorial(n-1);
}
->factorial(5);
<-120
```

Using return 0:

```
function factorial(n){
  if(n===0){
    return 0; //or return false;
  }
  return n * factorial(n-1);
}
->factorial(5);
<-0
```

Using return:

```
function factorial(n){
  if(n===0){
    return; // I don't know what it returns (true or false)?
  }
  return n * factorial(n-1);
}
->factorial(5);
<-NaN
```

So, what are the differences between return, return 0 or false, return 1 or true?

Comment: an empty return returns "undefined"

Comment: I don't know what it returns (true or false)?" - neither. it's `undefined`.

Comment: It depends on how you handle it

Comment: Look it up on the web. You could use Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+return. That would give you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return as the first result. About two lines down, it says "The expression to return. If omitted, undefined is returned instead."

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially forming a chain of multiplication operations:

```
factorial(3) * factorial(2) * factorial(1) ..
```

Which boils down to

```
3 * 2 * 1 ..
```

That `return` value you're changing will be the last part of this chain. If this last part is `1`, you'll get your regular result. If the last part is `0`, the result of the whole thing is `0`, because anything multiplied by 0 is 0. If you're not explicitly returning anything, the last value is `undefined`, and a multiplication operation with something that is not a number yields the value `NaN` (Not a Number), which essentially means the result has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorial(n){
  if(n===0){
    return 1; // actually here return 1 is necessary because it is using for multiplication in "n"  
  }
     var x =  factorial(n-1) ; //when n value will be n=1 then it return 1  so last return will be 5X4X3X2X(1 not 0 or true or false)
  return n*x;
}
```